# Roo custom finders in java classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I want to create a custom finder in my roo application. Most of the previous questions recommend creating the finders in the java classes, but I couldn't find the code to implement that and how to use it in my views or auto create the view.

Answer (score 1):

Create your finders using [finder add](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-finder-commands) command.

Then customize the JSP page, the controller handler method and the finder method as needed.